# Fatal error: Class 'WP_Customize_Section' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: *Class 'WP_Customize_Section' not found in* /home/acaopera/domains/acaoperatorulianeamt.ro/public_html/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-themes-section.php *on line* 19

I cant access my Appearance>Customize or even live preview for any theme i have installed, i deactivated all my plugins to try it out but i still have this problem. On my localhost , customize is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to log in to the server and delete (or rename) the theme folder.

The themes folder is located under:
`/wp-includes/wp-content/themes`